# How to Change the Tab (of a UITabViewController) Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to programatically select/change the tab of the UITabViewController.

I tried doing it via:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

This looks to be the way that I should do it, but it doesn't work. I thought that maybe the self.tabBarController returns a read only object (I sorta remember reading that somewhere), but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just to be sure - are you providing correct index? Tab index is **zero** based, so for second tab you should provide index 1.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set selectedViewController:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = viewControllerYouWant;
```

For example,

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController 
    = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, `selectedIndex` or `selectedViewController` are the properties you want and are both assignable.

The tabBarController property is readonly, but it returns an object that is editable.

So all your code looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me, if you want to do it by index.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this:

```
[root setSelectedViewController: [root.historyController navController]];
```